# SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap:Server' faultstring: 'Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: xml, web-services, ksoap2

I am not able to get the response from the web-service it showing the fault code as `soap:server` and fault string as `server was unable to process the request`

> 02-22 12:41:08.008: W/System.err(860): SoapFault - faultcode:
>   'soap:Server' faultstring: 'Server was unable to process request. --->
>   Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' faultactor:
>   'null' detail: org.kxml2.kdom.Node@413ecc90

Comment: have u used SOAP UI ? check the WSDL if you are missing a non-nullable element

Comment: i can;t able to get it wat u r trying to say...!

Comment: use SOAP UI for checking your web service and also look on error log of a web service. Server told - **it was unable to process request**. You have error in your request.

Comment: One of your object that sent to the Web Service is null, check your objects that sent to your web service for null before sending them to the web service in order to be processed by the web service.

Answer (score 0):

- check if the method name is correct.
- check if all params are added.
- check if all param names are correct (including case sensitive).